# How store values passed in macros?

Tags: elixir, metaprogramming

I have a next module where macros are defined:

```
defmodule BServer.Command do

  defmacro __using__(_)do
    quote do
      @before_compile unquote(__MODULE__)
      import BServer.Command, only: [command: 1, command: 2,
                                     command_description: 1]
      Agent.start(fn -> %{} end, name: unquote(__MODULE__))
    end
  end

  defmacro command(command_name, args \\[]) do
    quote do
      name = unquote(Atom.to_string(command_name))
      @command_name Keyword.get(unquote(args), :name, name)
      Agent.update(unquote(__MODULE__), &(Map.put(&1, unquote(command_name), __MODULE__)))
    end
  end

  defmacro __before_compile__(_env) do
    quote do
      def desc(), do: @command_desc
    end
  end

  def all do
      Agent.get(__MODULE__, &(&1))
  end


  def get(name) when is_atom(name) do
    Agent.get(__MODULE__, &(&1[name]), 100)
  end

  def get(name) when is_binary(name) do
    {command, _args} = parse(name)
    String.to_atom(command)
      |> get
  end

  def parse(message) do
    case Regex.run(~r/\w+\b/, message) do
      nil -> 
        {"", []}
      [command | args ] ->
        {command, args }
      [command] ->
        {command, []}   
    end
  end

  defmacro command_description(description) do
    quote do
      @command_desc unquote(description)
    end
  end
end
```

BServer.Command used in next module:

```
defmodule BServer.Command.Help do
  use BServer.Command

  command :help
  command_description """
    List of available commands
  """

  def process(user) do
    commands = 
      BServer.Command.all
        |> Enum.map(fn ({command, module}) -> 
          "#{command} - #{module.desc}"
        end)
        |> Enum.join("\n")
  end
end
```

In other place I dynamically define which module to use for process received commands:

```
    case BServer.Command.get(message) do
        nil -> false
        command ->
            BServr.User.get(user_attributes)
                |> command.process
    end
```

Faced with the problem that the Agent starts only when compiled and does not start when application was restarted.
How can I store the map "command" => "module which is responsible for handling" under the condition that the name of the command is given by the macro? Or can prompt another way to dynamically select the module to process the command. I want to keep all commands in separate modules for greater maintain and easy way to add new.

Comment: You want to collect the data on compilation stage and use it while the application is running. Use [`DETS`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/dets.html), or any other persistent storage of your choice. _Sidenote:_ you are abusing macros, overcomplicating things. For this particular task smth like `apply(Module.concat(BServer.Command, command_module), command, args)` is sufficiently enough, assuming that `{command_module, command}` are got from the input like `"help_help" |> String.split |> Enum.map(String.capitalize/1)` (⇐ pseudocode, but you got an idea.

Comment: Also, [`Module.__info__/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html#__info__/1) might be used here, assuming you expect your commands to live “together,” under some known in advance “common namespace.”

Comment: @mudasobwa Yes, I thought about variant with Module.concat/2, but it doesnt allow to get all commands name with registered modules in BServer.Command.all command for show all avaliable commands in help command response (for example). I started use macro b/c hope that it allow dynamically register commands modules in base module.